# Django encoding error in production with WSGI but not in development

Tags: django, character-encoding

I am getting the following error:

'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0160' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

in our production machine running the Django app using Apache+mod_wsgi. However, the same code works well in development in Eclipse. Is this somehow related to the WSGI config or a PYTHON path in the production machine?
Thanks!

Comment: If you have something in your path with the character `Š` then yes.

Comment: What is the traceback? Somewhere in your code you are encoding a unicode string to ascii and it can't convert u'\u0160'. If you are using Python 2, this can happen implicitly (e.g. `var = u'<unicode stuff here>'; print var`)

Comment: This is an excellent talk on the topic - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

Comment: I am aware of most of these issues what I don't understand why this issue only happens on Apache+WSGI and not within Eclipse dev environment (executing the same piece of code obvoiously)

Comment: There are many possibilities. Different OS, python version, etc... Can you post the traceback?

Comment: miki725, I only got what is in the apache error.log, not proper traceback. That error explains what happens and I managed to debug so far as to understand why incorrect encoding causes that error. However, what I don't understand is why this error never appeared when running the same code within Eclipse (same computer, OS, python version).

Comment: did anybody find the solution ? I am facing the same issue from long time